# How to convert NSSet to [String] array?

Tags: swift, nsset, swift-array

I have an NSSet of Strings, and I want to convert it into [String]. How do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use `map`:

```
let nss = NSSet(array: ["a", "b", "a", "c"])

let arr = nss.map({ String($0) })  // Swift 2

let arr = map(nss, { "\($0)" })  // Swift 1
```

[image: Swift 2]

[image: Swift 1]

Comment: swift 2 - says nsset doesn't have a map method and the second one forces me to do as! NSString - but ends up getting some dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional. So neither of them work for whatever reason

Comment: Works for me ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AFnfzlnodJtJBIq_wK4tRvGdoCwfTU5_2Ck)). Maybe upgrade Xcode? I'm using 7b4.

Comment: And here's the [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AFmdJD9SvyVMYLxPtmGj9aRVz6TolnczF7Q) for the Xcode 6 version. :)

Comment: Hey Eric! It works - only thing is I actually meant is for it to be an NSSet of "Tag"s with a "name" String field (instead of a NSSet of strings). How would I change the nss.map({ String($0) }) to work for this custom class "Tag"?

Comment: @noobprogrammer, he answered your question and you used his solution in the followup question.  Please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark to turn it green.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a `Set<String>`, you can use the Array constructor:

```
let set: Set<String> = // ...
let strings = Array(set)
```

Or if you have NSSet, there are a few different options:

```
let set: NSSet = // ...
let strings1 = set.allObjects as? [String] // or as!
let strings2 = Array(set as! Set<String>)
let strings3 = (set as? Set<String>).map(Array.init)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```
let set = //Whatever your set is
var array: [String] = []

for object in set {
     array.append(object as! String)
}
```

Comment: this ans made my day

Answer (score 2):

```
let set = NSSet(array: ["a","b","c"])
let arr = set.allObjects as! [String]
```